# Bug in sending multiple 2-D Arrays through socket.io

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am noticing a bug in socket.io. I am sending multiple (5) 2-D Array's through socket.io.  All of the Array's are coming through, at different lengths/sizes and at different times, if that matters with how node.js or socket.io handle them.  But they are seperate so I didn't think it mattered, just mentioning.

I have the incoming data from another source that populates Array1, Array2....ect. Here are some examples of what's happening, when sending through socket.io.

When I send test1: test1 does populate on the client side.

When I send test2: test2 does **not** populate on the client side.

when I send test2, **then** test1: test1 and test2 populate on the client side.

```
    var Array1 = [];
    var Array2 = [];        
    var Array3 = [];        
    var Array4 = [];
    var Array5 = [];

    jsonResults = JSON.stringify({
    'test1': Array1,
    'test2': Array2,
    'test3': Array3,
    'test4': Array4,
    'test5': Array5
    });
```

Just for an example of how I am calling variables on the client side

```
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('message', function(message){ 
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(message);

    var value1 = obj.test1[1][1];
    var value2 = obj.test2[0][5];
```

I have another question, If on the client side I call out a variable that doesn't exist like `obj.test1[5][5]` when test1 is only [4,5] sometimes it doesn't populate on the client side, for all the variables like `test1[1][1]` which does exist;  Is there a particular reason for this or am I approaching this wrong?

Is there a better way to program this from .js side  I have to handle multiple 2-D arrays of unknown size coming in at different times.

Server Side Listening to outside traffic.

```
// start UDP server listening on port 3001
udpRunningResultsServer.on("listening", function () {
var address = udpRunningResultsServer.address();
console.log("UDP Running Results Server listening on port: " +    address.port);
console.log(" ")
});
udpRunningResultsServer.bind(3001);

// process datagram
udpRunningResultsServer.on("message", function (Runningmsg, Runninginfo) { 
// check if datagram is full (size=536)
if(Runninginfo.size == 536){
    tempRunningResults = tempRunningResults + Runningmsg.toString();
} 
// datagram is not full, so this is the end of the message
else{
    finalRunningResults = tempRunningResults + Runningmsg.toString();

    RunningArray = finalRunningResults.split(';');          
    for (var a = 0; a < RunningArray.length; a++) {       
        var Runningtmp = RunningArray[a].length;              
        if (Runningtmp == 14 || Runningtmp == 0){
            RunningArray.splice(a,1);                  
        }
        else {
            RunningArray[a]= RunningArray[a].split(',');             
        }
    }
    RunningArray.unshift(time);
    tempRunningResults ='';                         
}
});

// start UDP server listening on port 3002
udpShotPutWeightThrowResultsServer.on("listening", function () {
var address = udpShotPutWeightThrowResultsServer.address();
console.log("UDP Shotput/Weight Throw Server listening on port: " + address.port);
console.log(" ")
});
udpShotPutWeightThrowResultsServer.bind(3002);

  // process datagram
  udpShotPutWeightThrowResultsServer.on("message", function   (ShotputWeightThrowmsg, ShotputWeightThrowinfo) { 

    tempShotputWeightThrowResults = ShotputWeightThrowmsg.toString();
    finalShotputWeightThrowResults = finalShotputWeightThrowResults+tempShotputWeightThrowResults;
    finalShotputWeightThrowResults = finalShotputWeightThrowResults.trim()
    console.log(finalShotputWeightThrowResults);
    //if (tempShotputWeightThrowResults == '~'){
    console.log(finalShotputWeightThrowResults);
    ShotputWeightThrowArray = finalShotputWeightThrowResults.split(';');            
    for (var a = 0; a < ShotputWeightThrowArray.length; a++) {    =
            ShotputWeightThrowArray[a]=      ShotputWeightThrowArray[a].split(',');         
        }
var serv_io = io.listen(htmlServer, { log: false });
serv_io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
//send data to client
setInterval(function(){
    jsonResults = JSON.stringify({
    'runningobj': ShotputWeightThrowArray,
    'shotputweightthrowobj': RunningArray,
    'longtriplejumpobj': LongTripleJumpArray,
    'highjumpobj': HighJumpArray,
    'polevaultobj': PoleVaultArray
    });                         
    console.log(jsonResults);
    socket.send(jsonResults);   
}, 1000);
});
```

Here is an example of what is coming through the socket.

```
{"runningobj":["0.0",["UNOFFICIAL","Decat Men 110 Meter Hurdles","nwi","41","6","4","041-6-04","AUTO","4"],["","2","504","Klaus Ambrosch","Arizona","","","","","","","","","",""],["","4","693","Troy McDonough","Montana","","","","","","","","","",""],["","6","818","Pat Buckheit","Tennessee","","","","","","","","","",""],["","8","746","James Cook","Penn State","","","","","","","","","",""],",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",",,,,,,,,,,,,,,",["\u0003\u0004"]],"shotputweightthrowobj":[["\u0001R\u0002Unofficial","HammerThrowWomen","","19","1","1","019-1-01",""],["1","1","79","Crozier","Unattached","33.55","","110'01\""],["~"],["","","","","","","",""],["~"],["","","","","","","",""],["~"],["","","","","","","",""],["~"]],"longtriplejumpobj":[],"highjumpobj":[],"polevaultobj":[]}
```

Comment: Where the codes of sending and recieving data?

Comment: I added the server listening side.  and I send it through Jsonstringify( .... like shown above that.  Then it receives it on the client side like shown above as well.  I know logic on converting the datagrams to strings is different on both of those but that is because they come in in different forms so I had to.  The end result though is shown below.

Comment: I understand that what you see there may look jumbled with arrays in arrays, (and maybe it can't be done like this).  But it does come through correctly, if I were to say run them on seperate scripts.  I wanted them together because I didn't want to start multiple node servers at once.